# how to fix ImportError python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I have a file beginning with `from moviepy.editor import *`.
when I run this file I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "moviepy.py", line 2, in 
>      
>  from moviepy.editor import *
>     
> File "/home/debian/Videos/moviepy.py", line 2, in 
>               from moviepy.editor import *
>   
> ImportError: No module named editor

the strange thing is I am 100% sure moviepy is installed.
I checked sys.path and in one of the paths is a folder called moviepy with multiple files inside including __init__.py __init__.pyc and editor.py
so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using virtual env? are you sure its in the current environment?

Comment: Yes I am using VMware, and I just followed the path from the sys.path to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename `moviepy.py` shadows installed package. Rename your main file and everything should work fine (if moviepy is installed in used interpreter).

Comment: If I rename it the problem is still there :(

Comment: maybe you have `moviepy` dir with `__init__.py` inside? Current working dir is first on look-up path so any naming conflicts would favor your local files and not interpreter installed packages.

Comment: Yes but I just renamed the file to something random and I still have the same problem.

Comment: *.pyc file may be left in cwd.

Comment: Thank you very much this was indeed the problem.